# Caché OREF Error - Getting More Information

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-ensemble

I'm am trying to integrate with a Caché Web Service and I'm getting an error message similar to:

> ERROR #5002: Cache error: <INVALID OREF>zMethodName+45^AA.wsClass.8

I do have have access to the code (albeit just a copy, so read-only), and I'm trying to decipher what the error could be pointing me to.

So does the number 45 and/or 8 mean anything? I've tried to see if it is pointing to a line number or offset from the method and I can't seem to pin point anything.

How might I be able to figure more out from this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard COS pointer. To locate it, just open routine AA.wsClass.8.INT, locate zMethodName and count 45 lines after it (or just write zMethodName+45 in Studio locator bar).

INVALID OREF means you try to use property or call method from null-valued pointer.